# Showing a span attribute value when hovering

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an HTML like this:

```html
<p id="IP08">Uneven development is, precisely that: capitalist
factors (firms, industries, countries) have a common trait, but
<span ref="capitalist factors (firms, industries, countries)">
they</span> show uneven unfolding and cannot be individually
predicted. Since the factors are mutually and interdependently
related, the general trend that we define as the law of uneven
development can be inferred from <span ref="capitalist factors
(firms, industries, countries)">their</span> relationship, which
has a specific connotation, i.e., the difference in the paces of
the factors that make up the relationship itself. Since the general
trend is determined by capitalism’s nature, <span ref="the general
trend">it</span> cannot change without changing the nature of
capitalism itself.</p>
```

How can I show the value of `ref` attribute of `span` tag when hovering on its text.

Comment: Have you tried adding the "pop-up" text to the `title` attribute? Or did you need it to be styled in some way? Have you made any attempts?

Comment: It works, thanks! Is there any way to use other attribute names like `ref`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use **title** attribute or you can make your own custom tooltip like the following example, in this case, be aware of positioning your tooltip to prevent overflows, in HTML you can add your custom attributes as well starting with **data-** for example **data-customAttribute**
the attribute selector in CSS looks like this `[data-customAttribute] {.....}` for more specificity you can add the element `span[data-customAttribute] {.....}`

```css
/** Tootip **/
  span[ref]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease .5s;
    visibility: visible;
    animation: grow 3s forwards;
}

span[ref]:after {
    content: attr(ref);
    background-color: #00adb5;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #00ADB5;
    border: 1px solid rgb(197, 195, 195);
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 20;
}

span[ref] {
    position: relative;
}

/* you can ignore the animation it is not mandatory */
@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }

    30%, 65% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    70%, 100% {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="IP08">Uneven development is, precisely that: capitalist
factors (firms, industries, countries) have a common trait, but
<span ref="capitalist factors (firms, industries, countries)">
they</span> show uneven unfolding and cannot be individually
predicted. Since the factors are mutually and interdependently
related, the general trend that we define as the law of uneven
development can be inferred from <span ref="capitalist factors
(firms, industries, countries)">their</span> relationship, which
has a specific connotation, i.e., the difference in the paces of
the factors that make up the relationship itself. Since the general
trend is determined by capitalism’s nature, <span ref="the general
trend">it</span> cannot change without changing the nature of
capitalism itself.</p>
```